# Make enyo.canvas fit

Tags: javascript, enyo

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9mhE/3/

Now I want to make the canvas control fit the parent div.
Since it inherits enyo.control I should be able to use the 'fit' property, but that does not seem to work.

is this a bug, or am I missing something

( http://enyojs.com/api/#enyo.Canvas )

The canvas control has a width and height property (default 500), maybe this overrides the fit property?

I must include code here, so:

```
enyo.kind({
    name: "App",
    kind: enyo.Control,
    fit: true,
    components: [
    {
        kind:enyo.Canvas,
        name:"canvas",
        fit:true

    }
    ]
});​
```

Comment: for now, I have fixed it like this http://jsfiddle.net/y9mhE/6/ (but it feels dirty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *fit* property does not belong to the enyo.Control kind, it can only be used inside a fittable kind. So change your apps kind to "FittableColumns" or "FittableRows" (or set layoutKind of "FittableColumnsLayout" or "FittableRowsLayout"), like this:

```
enyo.kind({
    name: 'App',
    kind: 'FittableColumns',
    /* or:
    kind: enyo.Control,
    layoutKind: 'FittableColumnsLayout', */
    components: [
        {
            name: 'canvas',
            kind: enyo.Canvas,
            fit: true // works now because of parents fittable layout
        }
    ]
});
```

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9mhE/7/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think this should be documented in the enyo.Control class, since 'fit' is documented as a property there

Comment: Yes that should be pointed out in the API docs. You could file a bug at the [Enyo bugtracker](https://enyojs.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa) or write a comment at the [forums](http://forums.enyojs.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I'm updating the inline docs for enyo.Control based on this.